# Whitelabel Error Page /There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipse-jee

I want to read a PDF file, but it gives me the error.
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/pdf/{id}", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public byte[] getPDF(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
        FichierTechnique fichierTechnique = fichierTechniqueDao.findById(id).get();
        return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/MasterAuto/" + fichierTechnique.getNameFichierTechnique()));

    }
```

Comment: Have a look at the server logs, they probably contain a more detailed error .

Comment: normally the code must work ?